# Render two Buttons in React but only one got the styling of the css Stylesheet

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently in the process of adding a stylesheet to my React Todo app. In the Todo component, two buttons are rendered that get the class clearButton or addButton depending on the label.

Button Component:

```
import './Button.css'


interface ButtonProps {
    lable: string,
    disabled: boolean,
    onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>    
}

export const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({ lable, disabled, onClick}): ReactElement => {
    
    
    let style: string = lable == 'ADD' ? 'addButton' : 'clearButton';
    console.log(lable);
    
    console.log(style);
    
    return(
        <div>
            <button className= {`button ${style}`} type='button' disabled= { disabled } onClick= { onClick }>
                {lable}
            </button>   
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

Strangely, only one styling of style class is ever applied to a button. It depends on which style class is in first place in the stylesheet. If the addButton class is in first place, only the styling of the addButton is displayed, if the clearButton class is in first place, only the styling of the other button is loaded.

```
.button {
    width: 70px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
};


.clearButton {
    background-color: #8c00ff;
}

.addButton {
    background-color: #7ce0ff;
}
```

Addutional

Parent Component

```
export const InputBar: FunctionComponent<InputBarProps> = ({ enterTodo, handleEnterTodo, handleCreateTodo, handleClearTodos}): ReactElement => {
    return(
          <>
            <div className="inputBar">
              <form>
                <TextField value={ enterTodo } onChange={ handleEnterTodo }/>
                <div className="buttonsContainer">
                  <Button lable= 'ADD'  disabled= { enterTodo == '' } onClick= { handleCreateTodo } />
                  <Button lable= 'CLEAR' disabled= { false } onClick= { handleClearTodos } />
                </div>
                
              </form>
            </div>
            
          </>
    );
}
```

Comment: i don't see why this code wont work, can you provide us with the parent component that uses the two buttons ?

Comment: I added the Parent Component. I check the Label at the Console.log output and it should be work